# How Windows Phone 8 mobile devices connected to the local Web services?

Tags: windows-phone-8

How Windows Phone 8 mobile devices connected to the local Web services ?

"System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException" unhandled exception of type occurs in System.Windows.ni.dll

Answer (score 0):

Although your question has many [room for improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) you could find a solution here [Consuming Local Web Applications](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2077111&seqNum=12) In short: you need to alter the configuration of IIS in order for Windows Phone 8 to be able to use your web services.

Comment: wcf deployed to iis, and then open the phone's wifi, wireless Internet access, and then use the Ip +address