# Calling a local web service using windows phone c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8

The web services are deployed in a JBoss Server locally.
I want to call the (localhost) web services from a windows phone emulator application.

when I call it using `http://localhost:80/webservice` I don't get any response from the server side.

**Solution (question is disabled by moderators, Can't write answer):** JBoss was not allowing any non local requests

Comment: Please, check the help and the FAQ to know how to post questions in this site.

Comment: localhost would be the Phone itself, not likely.

Comment: Altough unclear, possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18525364/how-windows-phone-8-mobile-devices-connected-to-the-local-web-services

Comment: ok @Rafa just i'm new here

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you've probably probably developing a rest service on your local machine and a windows phone app and you want the 2 to communicate with each other.

The issue your going to have is when you test your app its either going to be on a phone which wont see your machines localhost, or the simulator which is actually a virtual machine and therefore also wont see your localhost.

There are ways you can do it, but personally I find it easier just to publish your service to a free azue site.

Comment: The problem was in JBoss itself, permissions causes.